# How fast do I need to go to run on water?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, collision, estimation, drag

Well I was reading this article and I got stuck in this particular line

[image: 1]

because according to my calculations, the reaction of on my foot by the water should be $\rho A v^2 \sin^2\theta$. I am including a pic of my FBD:[image]

Mass of water pushed by foot in 1 second is $\rho Av\sin\theta$, and the velocity acquired by this water mass is $v \sin\theta$. Now, $\text{force} = \text{gain in momentum per second} = \rho Av^2\sin^2\theta$.

So, I cannot understand why this contradiction is happening and what is wrong with my math.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing whether any nonlinear behavior occurs when the pressure applied to the water is extremely high.   Compare, e.g., with the well-known non-Newtonian fluid   Oobleck.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Normal Pressure' that the article mentions is in the direction of the red arrow $F_1$,  so the upward force is the green component $F_2$

[image]

P.S. the original formula came from the consideration below

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes but how do I arrive at the magnitude of the pressure ?

Comment: $F_2$ is $F_1\cos\theta$, so it's $2\sin\theta\cos\theta\rho v^2 = \sin2\theta\rho v^2$ from the double angle formula for $\sin2\theta$

Comment: @  Möbius Did you mean  where does   $2sinθρv^2$ come from? It's from force needed from change in momentum of water of mass $\rho vA$, changing it by velocity $v$ so $P=\rho v^2$

Comment: shouldn't the mass of water be $\rho Avsin\theta$ ?

Comment: Also where does the 2 come in from in $2sin\theta \rho v^2$ ?

Comment: @ Möbius, see above comment, the $\sin\theta$ term is then due to the angle , think of the area presenting itself to the water as being $A\sin\theta$.  The factor two might be if they consider the change in water speed to be $v- -v = 2v$, as if the water has 'bounced' off the area.

Comment: I get why the 2 is being factored in but I still have my doubts about the $sin\theta$ term

Comment: @ Möbius, Ok, maybe time to have a think about it, all the best with it

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: @ Möbius sorry thought again and the edited answer is better